# How do I make a scatter plot of lines in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, line, scatter-plot

I have a series of paired xy coordinates that create 58 lines. I want to plot them on a Cartesian graph, values are between -5 and 5 on both axis, essentially making a scatter plot of lines. I have made something similar in matplotlib using the quiver function, but I want to be able to do this in D3. I would also like to be able to label each line, or each line that meets a length threshold. The code I have come up with below. Thanks.

```js
var lisa = [["Eloy",0.0169808,-0.695317,-0.0510301,-0.6995938],
["Florence",-0.3465685,-0.6790588,-0.5869514,-0.6762134],
["Phoenix",0.677068,-0.5754814,-0.6052215,-0.6158059],
["Tucson",-0.663848,0.4111043,-0.6722116,0.011639]]

var w = 200;
var h = 200;
//create the svg element and set the height and width parameters
var svg =  d3.select("div").select("div")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("height",h)
    .attr("width", w)
    .style("border", "1px solid black");

//Create the scale for the scatter plot
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d[0];}),d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[0];})])
    .range([-1,1]);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d[1];}),d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[1];})])
    .range([-1,1]);

//This is the function that creates the SVG lines
var line = svg.selectAll("line")
    .data(lisa)
    .enter()
    .append("line");

//This gets the cooresponding x,y cordinates from the dataset
line.attr("x1", function(d) {
    return xScale(d[0]);
})
.attr("y1", function(d) {
    return yScale(d[1]);
})
.attr("x2", function(d) {
    return xScale(d[2]);
})
.attr("y2", function(d) {
    return yScale(d[3]);
})
.attr("stroke", "black");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Showing us a bunch of code without an explanation that references that code doesn't tell us much. We have no idea what works and what doesn't or where your specific problem is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has some problems:

First, your range right now (`[-1, 1]`) makes no sense. This should be the domain instead (I changed the ranges to `[0, w]` and `[0, h]`).

In your real code, the domain should be `[-5, 5]` and the range should be the limits of the plot, something like `[leftLimit, rightLimit]` and `[topLimit, bottomLimit]` (have in mind that, in an SVG, the 0 position for the y axis is the **top**, not the bottom).

Second, given this array:

```
["Tucson",-0.663848,0.4111043,-0.6722116,0.011639]
```

your x and y positions should be the indices 1,2,3 and 4, not 0, 1, 2 and 3.

Besides that changes, I added the labels:

```
var text = svg.selectAll(".text")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("text");

text.attr("font-size", 10)
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return xScale(d[1]);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return yScale(d[2]);
    })
    .text(d => d[0]);
```

Here is the demo with the corrections:

```js
var dataset = [["Eloy",0.0169808,-0.695317,-0.0510301,-0.6995938],
["Florence",-0.3465685,-0.6790588,-0.5869514,-0.6762134],
["Phoenix",0.677068,-0.5754814,-0.6052215,-0.6158059],
["Tucson",-0.663848,0.4111043,-0.6722116,0.011639]];

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var w = 400;
var h = 300;
//create the svg element and set the height and width parameters
var svg =  d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("height",h)
    .attr("width", w)
    .style("border", "1px solid black");

//Create the scale for the scatter plot
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-1,1])
    .range([0,w]);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-1,1])
    .range([0,h]);

//This is the function that creates the SVG lines
var line = svg.selectAll("line")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("line");

//This gets the cooresponding x,y cordinates from the dataset
line.attr("x1", function(d) {
    return xScale(d[1]);
})
.attr("y1", function(d) {
    return yScale(d[2]);
})
.attr("x2", function(d) {
    return xScale(d[3]);
})
.attr("y2", function(d) {
    return yScale(d[4]);
})
.attr("stroke-width", 2)
.attr("stroke", (d,i)=>color(i));

var text = svg.selectAll(".text")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("text");

text.attr("font-size", 10)
.attr("x", function(d) {
    return xScale(d[1])+2;
})
.attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d[2]) + 4;
})
.text(d=>d[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem and then some.